# Silverlight touch exception on every control after a while

Tags: silverlight, exception, touch, multi-touch

At first it works fine, but after a while I get an exception when my Silverlight app is used by a touch screen device (Windows 7) and a user touches a button or a grid row.

```
Stack=
   bei MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)
   bei MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodPack(IntPtr objectPtr, String methodName, Object[] rawData)
   bei MS.Internal.XcpImports.TouchFrameEventArgs_GetTouchPoints(TouchFrameEventArgs args, UIElement relativeTo)
   bei System.Windows.Input.TouchFrameEventArgs.GetTouchPoints(UIElement relativeTo)
   bei WebShop.Views.TouchGestures.TouchScroller.Touch_FrameReported(Object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
```